# DateTime picker in Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datetimepicker

I want to add a datetime picker on my RoR app.
I add:
 1. jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js file in "assest/javascripts",
 2. jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css in "assest/stylesheets".
In .erb file, I add this:

```
<html>
   <head>
     <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-ui-timepicker-addon" %>
     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery-ui-timepicker-addon" %>
   </head>
   <body>
     <script>$('#ngo').datetimepicker();</script>
     <input type="text" id="ngo" />
   </body>
</html>
```

But when I run it. It have the following errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timepicker' of undefined             jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js:21
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timepicker' of undefined             jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js:21
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datetimepicker'
```

Any help?

Comment: make sure your jquery code is on document.ready, not right away in a script tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Link these script:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

**Or** you can also download these script and add to your application directory (`app/assets/javascripts/something.js or public/javascripts/something.js`)

And then add `<%= javascript_include_tag  "something" %>` to your application layout.

After that code HTML and JS

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class='tinytext' id="datepicker" name='time_from'>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat:'mm/dd/yy'
        });

</script>
```

Comment: you are welcome. :) please select this as answer (tic it). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This has been resolved by using the latest version of jquery.  Make sure to update your jquery.

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
      language: 'pt-BR'
    });
  });
</script>
```